# pgpool-II - Load balancing PostgreSQL instances

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, load-balancing, postgresql-9.1, pgpool

I'm using pgpool2 version 3.5.1 where there are 4 PostgreSQL 9.1 instances which has 16GB and 8 cores running on Ubuntu.

This is the pgpool.conf [file](http://pastebin.com/ZfdC2hqv).

As you can see in the conf file there are 4 instances which are

```
backend_hostname0 = '192.168.7.35' 
backend_hostname1 = '192.168.7.45'
backend_hostname2 = '192.168.7.46'
backend_hostname3 = '192.168.7.44'
```

The problem is data is replicated into backend_hostname1 and backend_hostname2 only. backend_hostname0 and backend_hostname3 is not being used by the pgpool2 for replication and load balancing.

Also I get below error when starting pgpool2

```
DEBUG:  find_primary_node: not in streaming replication mode
```

Why is that and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to comment on your post so far that's why I am making answer here.

try http://jensd.be/591/linux/setup-a-redundant-postgresql-database-with-repmgr-and-pgpool link for setting up your cluster and I am sure you will be done in one chance as I did.